# Java: generic Method - add elements to vararg

Tags: java, generics, methods

I want to do this here, it actually works but somehow I don't think that this is a good solution:

```
class A5<T> implements A4<T> {

    private final T[] elements;

    A5(T... elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }


    public <R> A5<R> map(Function<T, R> function) {
        List<R> liste = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T element : elements) {
            liste.add(function.apply(element));
        }
        Object[] objects = new Object[liste.size()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (R element : liste) {
            objects[counter] = liste.get(counter++);
        }
        return new A5(objects);
    }
}
```

For me the `Object[]` is a problem, but I cannot create a `R[]` array. Does anyone have a solution for it? Changing the CTOR and the signature of map is not what I am looking for. Only the body can be changed.

Comment: Side note: you understand that the names you are using A4, A5 are kinda really really saying nothing? And why are you declaring A5 to be generic, when you then instantiate an object of A5 without providing a type parameter, and using Object directly?

Comment: By not changing the CTOR, do you mean the body of it cannot be changed? Or the signature? Or both?

Comment: explv both Jägermeister I'm just not allowed to supply original source code here.

Comment: @N-rG In that case, you will need to use an `Object[]`, see my answer

Comment: Generic arrays are generally Bad.  Use a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a generic array, so unless you change the `T[]` to a `List<T>` in class `A5` you will need to create an `Object[]`.

Your code can be simplified a bit though. You can use a Java 8 Stream to map the elements and collect them to an `Object[]` and then cast this `Object[]` to an `R[]`. The `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` hides the warnings produced by the unchecked cast:

```
class A5<T> implements A4<T> {

    private final T[] elements;

    A5(T... elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R> A5<R> map(Function<T, R> function) {
        return new A5<>((R[]) Arrays.stream(elements).map(function).toArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to add a ctor, you could store your data in a list and thus do

```
class A5<T> implements A4<T> {

    private final List<T> elements;

    A5(T... elements) {
        this.elements = Arrays.asList(elements);
    }

    private A5(List<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }


    public <R> A5<R> map(Function<T, R> function) {
        List<R> list = elements.stream().map(function)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new A5(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: That also requires changing the initial constructor which OP specified he could not do. (Unless of course he only meant the signature could not be changed, in which case he should be more specific.)

Comment: @explv That's how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
public <R> A5<R> map(Function<T, R> function) {
    List<R> liste = new LinkedList<>();
    for (T element : elements) {
        liste.add(function.apply(element));
    }

    Object[] objects = liste.toArray();

    return new A5(objects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

The best you could do is get the most unspecific type of the objects returned by function, and use that to create a new array. Obviously that wont work when the array is empty or only null is return from function.

```
    Set<Class<?>> types = new HashSet<>();
    List<R> liste = new LinkedList<>();
    for (T element : elements) {
        R mapped = function.apply(element);
        types.add(mapped.getClass());
        liste.add(mapped);
    }

    Class<?> elementType = getMostUnspecifc(types);

    return new A5<R>(liste.toArray((R[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, liste.size()));
```

With helper method

```
static Class<?> getMostUnspecifc(Set<Class<?>> types) {
    if (types.isEmpty()) {
        return Object.class;
    }
    Class<?> unspecific = types.iterator().next();
    for (Class<?> type : types) {
        if (!unspecific.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            unspecific = type;
        }
    }
    return unspecific;
}
```